# Animate the highlight color when MouseOver ListviewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animated

I'm trying to animate the opacity of a Listviewitem, when you hover your mouse over it - I want the item to slowly fade into the highlightcolor, and when I remove my mousepointer, I want it to start fading out from whichever opacity it was on when the mouse got removed.

But how do you animate the highlight color, in any way?

Comment: You'll have to start by pulling out the style template for that control, then you can use a coloranimation storyboard for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, the ColorAnimation elements in the storyboards are what you will want to play with. I have it set to ramp up quickly (0.5 sec) but fade out slower (2 sec) so you can see it.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" Duration="00:00:00.5" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="Transparent" Duration="00:00:02" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#3DDADADA"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFDADADA"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.Items>
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 1" />
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 2" />
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 3" />
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 4" />
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 5" />
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You're welcome. In case you're curious, I created the ListView with one ListViewItem in it and then right-clicked the ListViewItem in the VS2013 Document Outline window. From the popup menu, I selected "Edit Template"->"Edit a copy...". From the "Create Style Resource" dialog that popped up, I picked Key:"Apply to all" and Define in:"This document -> Window". I then got rid of everything in the style except the Template, moved the style to the ListView (so it was self contained) and modified the IsMouseOver MultiTrigger.

Comment: Did not know you could do that! This will save me a lot of time! Thanks for this tip

Comment: Glad it was useful. Its like that old saying: Build a man a fire and he stays warm for a day. Set a man on fire and he stays warm for the rest of his life... Of course, the fishing version would also apply.